# Squid connection to 0.0.0.0 Failed

Tags: networking, proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

trying to set up a Squid transparent proxy. All is good for the transparency, however the proxy occasionally runs into errors such as "connection to 0.0.0.0 Failed"

Is this common? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what conditions does "occasionally" describe, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to connect to [0.0.0.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), as it's unroutable. If you are attempting to proxy to `0.0.0.0` in your configuration, more than likely someone got confused by its frequent appearance in listener definitions.

Comment: Well, the thing is that i'm not connecting to 0.0.0.0; I'm simply trying to access a normal site; ie. google.com. It doesn't happen every time, but it does.

Comment: Have you performed a grep on your config files to verify that `0.0.0.0` is only being used to specify an address to listen on?

Comment: Yes, I have. No clue what's going on here still :S